# Adding record on database

Tags: php, sql

I'm experiencing a strange problem with save query, and I'd like to better understand how to solve it.

I have a database with 2 tables, example:

```
TBL_PERSON
person_id
person_name
person_telephone

TBL_ADDRESS
address_id
address_person_id
address_address
address_city
address_zip
```

Now, I use a query like this to store records:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO TBL_PERSON ( 
    person_name,
    person_telephone
    ) VALUES (
    '$person_name',
    '$person_telephone'
    )";
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($sqlQuery);

//Get last id
$address_person_id = mysql_insert_id();

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO TBL_ADDRESS ( 
    address_person_id,
    address_address,
    address_city,
    address_zip
    ) VALUES (
    '$address_person_id',
    '$address_address',
    '$address_city',
    '$address_zip'
    )";
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($sqlQuery);
```

Sometimes, no record is added on `TBL_ADDRESS`.
After the user presses `Insert`, `Action Button`, `Name` and `Telephone` are stored on `TBL_PERSON`, but not address on `TBL_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Are you checking for possible empty fields? Plus, you may want to put this in lowercase `MYSQL_QUERY` whether it makes a difference or not, I've never tried it.

Comment: check for mysql_error (or even better start using mysqli or PDO).

Comment: Fred, problem can be on database with NOT NULL fields?

Comment: Bojan, you mean mysql_error.log file?

Comment: Hard to say. Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if that yields anything.

Comment: As far as we can see from this code, none of the variables in the insert queries are properly escaped.  Content in them like a single quote will break the SQL statement.  At a minimum to fix this code, you must do `$address_address = mysql_real_escape_string($address_address);` (for all those variables).  But the _real_ fix is to switch to an API supporting prepared statements and parameterized queries.  See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for examples via MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: To on @MichaelBerkowski comment, the [mysql api you are using is depreciated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Before you solve anything else you should switch.

Comment: Michael, yes, i have mysql_real_escape_string already present. I have wrote this query in real time...

Comment: If all variables are properly escaped and you have a value for `$address_person_id` but this is intermittent, you will need to log errors when it happens.  `if (!$result) error_log('Error inserting address: ' . mysql_error());` and monitor your web server's error log.

Comment: i meant use mysql_error function in php. or print string that php build that you use for mysql_query and try to execute it manually.

Comment: Thanks all for time spent. I'm going to check out all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring the [discussion on the use of deprecated an insecure `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), I think this is a good opportunity to explain methods of debugging issues like this.

In the replacements for the mysql_* query functions, exceptions are thrown on errors allowing you to wrap the query in a `try`/`catch` block and handle it accordingly. In the case of `mysql_query()`, you will simply get `false` returned from the function. So to be able to debug and consequently see what is wrong, you need to do something like this ([from the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM myTable');
if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

If your query fails, you will see **why**, which is important in debugging.

As mentioned in the comments, you do not escape any of your values. Aside from the fact that you shouldn't be using these functions at all (see [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)), you should at minimum be escaping your values using the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) method:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

If you follow the above logic, you will see what is causing the issue, and I suspect fix it successfully using proper escaping of values. If it's not the value, you may have an issue with your database schema design such as a column that is not nullable and has no default value, yet you may be passing a null value.